# Connecting to MSOLAP cube trough DBI

Tags: r, database, olap, olap-cube, r-dbi

I would like to connect to a Microsoft Olap Cube using the 'DBI' interface instead of the MCRAN package 'olapR' because it is only available on Windows version and therefore I cannot containerize it when my work is done.

So far I tried:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
Driver   = "MSOLAP",
Server   = "xxx.net",
Database = "yyy",
UID      = "")
```

But with no luck.

Provided that the connection string I use in Excel is:

```
Provider=MSOLAP.8; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=""; Initial Catalog=""; Data Source=xxx.net\yyy; Location=xxx.net
```

Comment: Can you try creating an ODBC connection to your database first, test it, and then use that DSN in the `dbConnect()` call?

Comment: How can I get an ODBC connection string? The only thing excel returns me is a .odc file which contains again that string.

Comment: Are there really no ODBC drivers for OLAP? https://www.connectionstrings.com/olap-analysis-services/

Comment: Does the following help: https://a.kabachnik.info/run-mdx-queries-on-ssas-cubes-via-odbc-or-php-sqlsrv-extension.html?

Comment: From connectionstrings.com seems like no ODBC drivers are available, then I tried creating a user DSN using the SQL server driver but even with windows authentication enabled is not connecting throwing error 18456 login not valid

Comment: AFAIK, there is no xplat Analysis Services connector generally. re: olapR, yes it's windows only. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/introducing-r-server-r-package-reference

Comment: I shared on Twitter: https://twitter.com/krlmlr/status/1341784779453304832.

Comment: olapR is indeed getting old... ``` 
Package: olapR
Title: OLAP Cube access in R
Version: 1.0.0
Author: 'Microsoft Corporation'
Description: OLAP Cube access in R
Depends: R (>= 3.2.2)
Suggests: testthat
License: file LICENSE
Built: R 3.5.2; x86_64-w64-mingw32; 2019-05-21 01:50:41 UTC; windows
Archs: x64
```